# Strongly Typed List.GroupBy()

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I've been trying to find an answer to this on google and on SO

but everywhere I have found uses anonymously typed result lists

what I am trying to acheive is to take a `List<SecondaryStandard>`

and create a grouped List of `SecondaryStandard`

each `SecondaryStandard` looks like this

```
public class SecondaryStandard
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int IdNumeric { get; set; }
    public string IdText { get; set; }
    public Sample Sample { get; set; }
    public string StandardName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public SamplePoint SamplingPoint{ get; set; }
    public Instrument Instrument{ get; set; }
    public string ContainerId { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public string PointLocation { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Description2 { get; set; }
    public string Analysis { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }

}
```

what i want is a List() where the Value Property is an average of results for each ComponentName.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this in a strongly typed way or do I need to suck it up and use anonymous objects to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: `List<>` doesn't have a value property.  You would need to create a custom collection type that has one.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what the result would be? Give us an example `List<SecondaryStandard>` with values, and then the desired result you want, and then we can see about how to get there.

Comment: Value is a property of SecondaryStandard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this?

```
List<SecondaryStandard> list = new List<SecondaryStandard>();
// populate list

List<SecondaryStandard> result = list
    .GroupBy(l => l.ComponentName)
    .Select(s => new SecondaryStandard() { ComponentName = s.Key, Value = s.Average(x => x.Value) }).ToList();
```